# evaluate $\iiint\limits_{B}^{} \cosh \left ( x+y+z \right ) dxdydz$, where $B=\left \{ \left ( x,y,z \right ) \in R^3|x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1 \right \} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates

> Evaluate $\iiint\limits_{B}^{} \cosh \left ( x+y+z \right ) dxdydz$, where $B=\left \{ \left ( x,y,z \right ) \in R^3|x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1 \right \} $

Since B is a unit ball which centers at the origin,
I think it should be highly usefull to change coordinates to spherical coordinates. And of course, by definition, $$\cosh\left (  x+y+z\right )  = \frac{e^{x+y+z}+e^{-x-y-z}}{2}$$ But after changing coordinates, I still know little about how to integral such thing like......$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \cosh \left ( r\sin \phi \cos \theta+r\sin \phi \sin \theta+r\cos \phi \right )r^2\sin \phi drd\phi d\theta $$
or$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{\left ( r\sin \phi \cos \theta+r\sin \phi \sin \theta+r\cos \phi \right )}+e^{\left ( -r\sin \phi \cos \theta-r\sin \phi \sin \theta-r\cos \phi \right )}}{2} r^2\sin \phi drd\phi d\theta $$

Could anyone give some hints how I can do it please?

Comment: It might be useful to rotate the coordinate system. Then the integral might become simpler and easier to compute.

Comment: @richrow Sir, would you please explain more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this change of variables:

- $X=\frac1{\sqrt2}(x-y)$
- $Y=\frac1{\sqrt6}(x+y-2z)$
- $Z=\frac1{\sqrt3}(x+y+z)$

Note that $(x,y,z)\mapsto\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}(x-y),\frac1{\sqrt6}(x+y-2z),\frac1{\sqrt3}(x+y+z)\right)$ is a linear map and, more precisely, it is an orthogonal transformation; in particular, the absolute value of its determinant is equal to $1$, it is injective, and it maps $B$ onto $B$.

So, after doing this change of variable, your integral becomes$$\iiint_B\cosh\left(\sqrt3Z\right)\,\mathrm dX\,\mathrm dY\,\mathrm dZ.$$Now, using spherical coordinates, this becomes\begin{multline}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1\cosh\left(\sqrt3\rho\cos\varphi\right)\rho^2\sin\varphi\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\varphi\,\mathrm d\theta=\\=2\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^1\cosh\left(\sqrt3\rho\cos\varphi\right)\rho^2\sin\varphi\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\varphi.\end{multline}But\begin{multline}\int_0^1\cosh\left(\sqrt3\rho\cos\varphi\right)\rho^2\sin\varphi\,\mathrm d\rho=\\=\frac1{18}\sec\varphi\bigl(\sqrt3(3\cos(2\varphi)+7)\sec\varphi\sinh\left(\sqrt{3}\cos\varphi\right)-12\cosh\left(\sqrt3\cos\varphi\right)\bigr)\tan\varphi\end{multline}and\begin{multline}\int_0^\pi\sec\varphi\bigl(\sqrt3(3\cos(2\varphi)+7)\sec\varphi\sinh\left(\sqrt{3}\cos\varphi\right)-12\cosh\left(\sqrt3\cos\varphi\right)\bigr)\tan\varphi\,\mathrm d\varphi=\\=12\cosh\left(\sqrt3\right)-4\sqrt3\sinh\left(\sqrt3\right).\end{multline}Therefore, your integral is equal to$$\frac\pi9\left(12\cosh\left(\sqrt3\right)-4\sqrt3\sinh\left(\sqrt3\right)\right).$$

Comment: @JeanMarie If $x,y,z\in\Bbb R^3$, then $\cosh(x+y+z)\geqslant1$, and therefore$$\iiint_B\cosh(x+y+z)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\geqslant\iiint_B1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz=\frac43>1.145.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sir, is there any alternatives(perhaps more basically please?) to solve this problem??

Comment: If I was aware of such an alternative, I would have posted it instead of this one.

Comment: After you did transform $x,y,z\to X,Y,Z$, how do you guarantee the region is still a unit ball for $X, Y, Z$ ?

Comment: @MathFail It follows from the fact that my transformation is orthogonal. In particular, it maps vectors into vectors with the same norm.

Comment: Why downvoting? This answer is correct! (+1)

Comment: [+1] Same comment as Robert Z.

Comment: At last, and thanks to Robert Z, I have found the same answer as you...

Comment: @JeanMarie Unlie Robert Z, I failed to see what was missing in your approach. The idea looked fine to me. I'm glad that you were able to correct it. (+1)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you sir! Sir, may I ask how it occurs to you to change coordinates like you did? It was pretty cool~

Comment: @mlrofcloud Two things. In the first place, since I was integrating a function of the type $f(x+y+z)$, it would be useful if one of my new coordinates was a multiple of $x+y+z$. And I wanted to have an orthogonal transformation, so that the unit ball was preserved and the absolute value of the Jacobian was $1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you, sir, this helps a lot!

Comment: @mlrofcloud I suggest that you accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Fig. 1 : The unit ball modelized as a pile of cylinders with common axis (D) with equation (2) (in blue) and infinitesimal height. A plane $P_k$ with equation (1) which is represented by its trace, a red triangle, on the coordinate planes ; its intersection with the unit ball is a disk. The coordinate axes are represented in black.*

Let us consider planes $P_k$ with equation :

$$x+y+z=k\tag{1}$$

They share a common orthogonal line $(D)$ with equation $$x=y=z\tag{2}$$

- Plane $P_k$ intersects line $(D)$ in point $I_k:=(k/3,k/3,k/3)$
- Plane $P_k$ intersects the unit ball along a circle with center $I_k$ and radius $r(k)$ such that (Pythagorean theorem) :

$$(OI_k)^2+r(k)^2=1 \ \iff \ r(k)^2=1-k^2/3$$

**Remark :** one must have  $-\sqrt{3} \le k \le \sqrt{3}$ in order that plane $P_k$ intersects the unit ball.

Therefore, if we consider the unit ball as represented by an "almost spherical" paper lantern made of a "pile" of cylinders with infinitesimal height $dk$ having base disks with radius $r(k)$, the triple integral is reduced to this single integral :

$$\int_{k=-\sqrt{3}}^{k=+\sqrt{3}}\cosh(k)\underbrace{(\pi r(k)^2)}_{\text{disk area}}\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}dk$$

$$=\frac{4\pi}{3 \sqrt{3}} \left(\sqrt{3}\cosh\left(\sqrt{3}\right)-\sinh\left(\sqrt{3}\right)\right) \approx 5.5878$$

finding back the result of José Carlos Santos (computation made by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28%282*pi%29%2Fsqrt%283%29%29*cosh%28x%29*%281-%28x%5E2%29%2F3%29+from+0+to+sqrt%283%29)).

The presence of $\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}$ has to be explained : when we move from $k$ to $k+dk$, dist$(I_k,I_{k+dk})$ is the diagonal of a cube whose sides are $dk/\sqrt{3}$.

**Many thanks to @Robert Z who has pointed a big double error of mine.**

(for interested readers) Here is the Matlab which has generated the figure ; please note that the pile of cylinders has initialy been obtained with the $z$ axis as common axis, then, all them have undergone a rotation with angle $\theta=\operatorname{atan}(\sqrt{2})$ and axis $(-1,1,0)$ in order that the $z$ axis becomes the $(D)$ axis. This rotation is obtained as the exponential of a certain antisymmetrical matrix.

```
 clear all;close all;axis equal,axis off;hold on;
 L='linewidth';
 t=-1:0.01:1;
 k=9;T=round(k*t)/k;
 r=sqrt(1-T.^2);[X,Y,Z]=cylinder(r);
 a=1/sqrt(2);th=atan(sqrt(2));
 R=expm(th*[0,0,a;0,0,a;-a,-a,0]); % rotation matrix
 [p,q]=size(X); % p=201 ; q=21
 U=[X(:),Y(:),Z(:)]';S=R*U;
 X1=reshape(S(1,:),p,q);
 Y1=reshape(S(2,:),p,q);
 Z1=reshape(S(3,:),p,q);
 surf(X1,Y1,Z1);view(70,30);
 u=1.5;v=2.5;w=1.5;
 plot3(u*[0,1],u*[0,1],u*[0,1],L,5); % line x=y=z
 plot3([v,0,0,0,0],[0,0,v,0,0],[0,0,0,0,v],'k',L,2) % axes
 I=eye(3);T=w*I(:,[1,2,3,1])
 plot3(T(1,:),T(2,:),T(3,:),'r',L,5); % triangle
```

Comment: Are the axes of the cylinders orthogonal to the planes $E_k$? (Parallel to line $x=y=z$?)

Comment: @Alex Ortiz Yes, they even have line (D) $x=y=z$ as their **common axis** (the paper lantern has to be consider slanted)

Comment: Your integral should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{k=-\sqrt{3}}^{k=+\sqrt{3}}\cosh(k)(\pi r(k)^2) dk$ which gives the same result of  José Carlos Santos. $\pi r(k)^2$ is the area of the infinitesimal disk given by the intersection of the plane $x+y+z=k$ and the unit ball

Comment: @Robert Z Thanks a lot ! I am an idiot...

Comment: @Robert Z I am puzzled by the presence of the "frontal" $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$... Is it a jacobian ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, it is.

Comment: Text fixed... at last.

Answer (score 3):

**Computing the Integral via a Change of Coordinates**

We have the orthonormal change of coordinates
$$
\begin{align}
u&=\frac{x+y+z}{\sqrt3}\\
v&=\frac{x-z}{\sqrt2}\\
w&=\frac{x-2y+z}{\sqrt6}
\end{align}\tag1
$$
Then the integral becomes
$$
\begin{align}
\int_B\cosh(x+y+z)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\int_B\cosh\left(u\sqrt3\right)\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}w\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2a}\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\pi\left(1-u^2\right)\cosh\left(u\sqrt3\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}\int_{-1}^1u\sinh\left(u\sqrt3\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac{4\pi}3\cosh\left(\sqrt3\right)-\frac{2\pi}3\int_{-1}^1\cosh\left(u\sqrt3\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2d}\\
&=\frac{4\pi}3\cosh\left(\sqrt3\right)-\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt3}\sinh\left(\sqrt3\right)\tag{2e}\\
&=\frac{4\pi}3\left(\cosh\left(\sqrt3\right)-\frac{\sinh\left(\sqrt3\right)}{\sqrt3}\right)\tag{2f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ apply $(1)$
$\text{(2b):}$ integrate in $v$ and $w$;
$\phantom{\text{(2b):}}$ since $u^2+v^2+w^2\le1$, for a given $u$,
$\phantom{\text{(2b):}}$ $v^2+w^2\le1-u^2$: a disk of radius $\sqrt{1-u^2}$
$\text{(2c):}$ integrate by parts
$\text{(2d):}$ integrate by parts
$\text{(2e):}$ integrate
$\text{(2f):}$ simplify

---

**Motivation for the Change of Coordinates**

What we want to get is an orthonormal set of vectors.  We start with an orthogonal set of vectors, and then normalize each one.

The first vector is $(1,1,1)$ because we want $x+y+z$ to be a variable; that is because $\cosh(x+y+z)$ is the integrand.

One choice for an orthogonal vector is something like $(1,0,-1)$; that is,
$$
(1,1,1)\cdot(1,0,-1)=0\tag3
$$
For the third vector, because we have $(1,0,-1)$, we want the first and last entries equal; that is, a vector like $(1,\alpha,1)$, since
$$
(1,0,-1)\cdot(1,\alpha,1)=0\tag4
$$
We choose $\alpha$ so that
$$
0=(1,1,1)\cdot(1,\alpha,1)=2+\alpha\tag5
$$
That is, we have $(1,-2,1)$.

Now we normalize, so that they all have norm $1$:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle\frac{(1,1,1)}{\sqrt3}\\
\displaystyle\frac{(1,0,-1)}{\sqrt2}\\
\displaystyle\frac{(1,-2,1)}{\sqrt6}
\end{array}\tag6
$$
This leads to the change of variables in $(1)$.

Comment: Sir, may I ask how it occurs to you to change coordinates like you did? It was pretty cool~

Comment: @mlrofcloud: I have appended a section on the motivation for the choice of the change of coordinates.

Comment: Thank you sir, this really helps a lot!